Rotted wood under window - fixable or do I need a professional to replace everything?
No project in a 100+ year old house is ever easy.
I went to replace the window stool in one of my windows because it was cracked and chipping. When I removed the old stool, I found the wood underneath the stool and the wood frame underneath the window was very badly rotted. It was just crumbling when I lightly touched it with a screwdriver (last photo). This is the window where the AC goes, so I don't know if one of the previous owners had an AC leak that caused water damage?
My plan had been to remove all the crumbling, rotted wood, and put wood hardener and wood epoxy on the rest of the wood that was just a little soft to the touch. Once I got started with removing the rotted wood, a lot more of it was damaged than I thought. You can see in the first photo below that I had to remove the entire framing piece that was under the window and on one side, there's about a 6" void in the wall that's left. I think maybe it was some of the vertical framing that had been damaged too that I removed that left the hole.
Can I just fill in these areas with new wood or do you think this is so far gone that I need to call in a professional to remove the window and reframe the whole thing properly again? I'm not sure how structural the wood frames around the windows are.





This is subject to your confidence in your skills.  Replacing framing isn't necessarily hard, but recognize that every time you tear something out you will get surprises.  Note that you also need to find and fix the water leak that caused this.
